# No usa listeners pasivos para mejorar el desplazamiento

Tags: bootstrap, bootstrap-4, seo

Al usar herramientas como PageSpeed Insights y analizar mi sitio web me arroja ciertas advertencias que causan que el rendimiento no sea el mejor como se ve en el titulo estoy tratando de resolver este error por decirlo así.

> No usa listeners pasivos para mejorar el desplazamiento

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero visualizando esto me refleja al usar el siguiente codigo.

```
 <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 py-1">
        <div id="map-container-google-11" class="z-depth-1-half map-container-6">
          <iframe title="Clínica Equilibrium Rancagua" class="col-12 col-sm-12"
            src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d13203.992548140799!2d-70.7154716!3d-34.1719653!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0xedf120ae507f044b!2sClinica%20Equilibrium%20Rancagua!5e0!3m2!1ses-419!2sec!4v1618111761481!5m2!1ses-419!2sec"
            height="550" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="0"></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Pero tomando en cuenta mi código no veo donde pueda realizar la modificación, con lo cual acudo a ustedes para saber si alguien ha pasado por lo mismo y me puede dar una mano con esto.

De antemano les agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: 1. El código con la problemática es directamente el código de google, no hay mucho que puedes hacer, 2. Lo que te reportan son advertencias, sugerencias, no necesariamente tengan razón, en este caso, google maps es demasiado complejo como para que un simple linter diga si hacen bien o mal a la hora de agregar listeners no pasivos.

Comment: Básicamente tendría que dejar pasar por decirlo y continuar con las demás sugerencias que me realiza la pagina.

Comment: Exactamente, como regla general, no tomes las advertencias como errores, hay casos puntuales donde no existe otra solución. Puedes ver las advertancias como "normalmente no necesitas esto" pero de necesitarlo, está bien ignorar la advertencia.

Comment: Listo,  te agradezco tu ayuda y tu tiempo por la explicación.